# Pygame/Pip installation issues

Tags: python, pygame

Recently I've been interested in pygame, and installed pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32 on my 64-bit ASUS windows computer.

I saved it to C:/python34/Scripts.

From that directory, in cmd, I ran the line "pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32"

and got this error:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Python34\Scripts>pip3 install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32
Collecting pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32

I've tried all kinds of different things. I ran the pip update command and tried again, but nothing is working.

Comment: All you need to do is: `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 1):

Where did you download the module from? 
If its not precompiled pip will not be able to install without the correct version of Microsoft Visual Studio install, and most likely a bunch of other prerequisites.

My guess is that you downloaded a compiled version from a site such as this well known one http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

First don't save it to \Python34\Scripts there is no need to pollute this directory instead save it to your desktop or a downloads folder.

Second if the file has a whl extension you need to add that to the file name when running the pip command.

Third is the version of python you are using 32bit if not you need to find a 64 bit version of that module.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I still don't know what went wrong, but I reinstalled everything and ran cmd as admin an it all worked out! :)